# PHP loop through exploded values to populate an array

Tags: php, arrays

in my database I store a filePath containing all the uploaded documents.  It looks something like the following

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portal\Portal\public\uploads\Weekly Complete
>   Jobs.docx&&&C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portal\Portal\public\uploads\Wish
>   List.docx&&&

So I have separated each filepath by using

> &&&

In PHP, I then explode this filepath and then I want to loop each path and add it to an array.  At the moment, I have something like this

```
$attachments = array();
if(!empty($this->project->dsReportingDoc->filePath)) {
    $string = explode("&&&", $this->project->dsReportingDoc->filePath);
    foreach($string as $key=>$path){
        if(!empty($path)){
            $attDoc = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)));
            $attachments = [(
                array(
                    "Id" => $key,
                    "Version" => $key,
                    "File" => array(
                        "Name" => $path,
                        "Content" => $attDoc
                    )
                )
            )];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that it only seems to be adding the last path to the array because I think the others are being overriden.

How can I get them all added to this array?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you overwrite $attachments, try $attachments[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$attachments[] = 
    array(
        "Id" => $key,
        "Version" => $key,
        "File" => array(
            "Name" => $path,
            "Content" => $attDoc
        )
    )
;
```